# Using AsyncTask callback to contruct objects backing ListView

Tags: android, listview, callback, android-asynctask

I am trying to figure out a way to get specific values that are needed for the objects displayed in a `ListView`. In the example below, I am building a list of users. I use an existing array to supply some of the values but need to dynamically check for/get pictures associated with that user from the server.

```
private void getUsers(JSONArray userArray){
    users = new ArrayList<User>();
    int length = userArray.length();
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, userArray.toString());
    try{

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            User u = new User();
            u.setProfileId(userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("profileid"));
            u.setDisplayName(userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("displayname"));
            u.setStatus(userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("status"));
            u.setId(userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
            if(memCache.contains(u.getDisplayName())){
                u.setProfilePicture(memCache.getBitmapFromMemCache(u.getDisplayName())); 
            } else {
                downloadPicture(u.getProfileId(), u.getDisplayName());
            }
            users.add(u);
        }
        users.add(createBlankUser());
        updateUserListView(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void downloadPicture(String profileId, final String displayName){
    GetUserProfilePicture getPic = new GetUserProfilePicture(new OnUserPictureDownloaded(){

        @Override
        public void downloadFinished(Bitmap b) {
            if(b != null){
                if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Download finished " + b.toString() + " " + displayName);
                memCache.addBitmapToMemoryCache(displayName, b);
            }
        }
    });
    getPic.execute(profileId);
}
```

The `AsyncTask` and methods in its class all do what they are supposed to. I get the image returned properly from the server. The issue is that I can't link the result of the `AsyncTask` to a particular object before I add it to the list. In case that made no sense, in the past when I was using a private `AsyncTask` within this activity I could just run any I/O and object building methods in the background together so that the downloading of the images would correspond to the object being constructed at that time. Now that I have made the `AsyncTask` its own class (which is better for the overall structure of the app) I'm having a hard time taking the value returned by the interface and using.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you having problems using an interface? Obviously, I know that it takes a little bit more coordination than an inner class. Other than that? An interface should be the best way to achieve what you're talking about.

Comment: Well the problem is coordinating the result of the asynctask with the list objects. The task downloads but not inline (obviously because its an asynctask). So that I cant set its result as a value in the object i am making in that for loop because it is not available at that time.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand what you're talking about. I actually had a similar problem. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're needing to detect when the `AsyncTask` is finished, pass in your downloaded values, and do appropriate object initialization from there.

The way that I accomplished this was through a custom interface that I named `OnTaskFinishedListener`. In the constructor for the `AsyncTask`, I pass in an `Activity` reference (if in a `Fragment` I also pass in a `Fragment` reference) and cast a reference of `OnTaskFinishedListener` to either my `Activity` reference or my `Fragment` reference depending on whether the code was in an `Activity` or a `Fragment`. After that, I implement the interface in the `Activity` or `Fragment` that I need to receive the callback in and do initialization in there. It's always easier to explain with code, so here it is:

```
public interface OnTaskFinishedListener {
    /* Pass our information to the Activity or Fragment that started this 
    AsyncTask once our custom Asynctask finishes.*/
    public void onTaskFinished(/*Varargs or variable(s) as parameter(s)*/);
}

public class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {
    Activity activity;
    Fragment fragment;
    OnTaskFinishedListener mListener;

    // Running the task from an activity
    public CustomTask(Activity activity) {
         this.activity = activity;
         try {
             mListener = (OnTaskFinishedListener) activity;
         } catch (ClassCastException e) {
             Log.e(SOME_TAG, activity.toString() + " must implement " +
             "OnTaskFinishedListener."
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    // Running the task from a Fragment
    public CustomTask(Activity activity, Fragment fragment) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.fragment = fragment;

        try {
             mListener = (OnTaskFinishedListener) fragment;
         } catch (ClassCastException e) {
             Log.e(SOME_TAG, activity.toString() + " must implement " +
             "OnTaskFinishedListener."
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    ...

    protected Object doInBackground(Object... urls) {
        // Background work here
        return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        mListener.onTaskFinished(result);
    }

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     ...

    public void onTaskFinished(Object result) {
        // TODO object initialization, ListView backing, loops, etc.
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will accept because this is the approach I had already implemented above. What actually happened was an issue with the adapter backing my listview, not the items themselves. Always check the adapter.

Comment: Ah yes. I can't tell you how many times I've thought the ListView was messing up, when it was actually a problem with my adapter. Glad that you got it fixed though and sorry that my answer wasn't more on target. ;)